# When adding two almost identical tuples to a set make them be considered the same

Tags: python, set

I have a list of tuple objects all with the same number of elements. Now I would like to put all unique tuple objects into a different list. This is a relatively easy thing to do. However the elements in my tuple objects are of type float. Because of rounding errors certain tuples that would otherwise be identical for example (1.0000000, 5.0000000, 7.0000001) and (1.0000001, 5.0000000, 7.0000000), will be considered as unique when adding them to a set. Here I am adding the values manually, in actuality they will be assigned after performing certain calculations. So is there a way for two tuples that are almost identical to be considered the same when adding them to a set?

```
 myTuple = (1.0000000, 5.0000000, 7.0000001)
 myTuple2 = (1.0000001, 5.0000000, 7.0000000)
 myList.append(myTuple)
 myList.append(myTuple2)
 #add more tuples

 mySet = set()
 newList = []
 for x in myList:
    if x not in mySet:
        mySet.append(x)
        newList.append(x)
```

Comment: Round the values to the desired precision *before* adding them directly to `mySet`.

Comment: @chepner how many digits would you recommend I round floats to?

Comment: 2 questions that would help shape an answer:  how close do they need to be in order for you to consider them the same?  If you are just accounting for numerical error & rounding maybe 1e-3?  Also, do you need to preserve the full accuracy of the number or can you do as suggested above and round them before and loose the decimal dust?  Comparing floats is usually done with some small delta...

Comment: @JeffH I would like to preserve the full accuracy if possible of one of the floats that are almost identical. Can I somehow compare each value with an small delta like 1e-7 (to check for rounding errors) in a fast way? I may have ten of thousands of tuples in a list, so comparing them using a loop would be really really slow.

Comment: Probably so...but your question is a bit confusing.  If you use some small delta for comparison for the purposes equality for putting the thing into a set, you will only retain one of them...so then the full accuracy doesn't seem to be important as one or the other will enter the set, but not both.  Is that correct?

Comment: @JeffH Yeah you are right. After some further thinking I think it would suit me to round the values to about 1e-6. How would I do that? Should I use `round()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, you don't need both a list and a set to hold the answers, you can just catch them all in the set.  You can use a set comprehension to make the set:

```
# three tuples, 2 equivalent when rounded to 6 places
t1 = (1.12345678, 2.0, 3.0)
t2 = (1.12345671, 2.0, 3.0)
t3 = (5.76, 9.842, 3.001)

inputs = [t1, t2, t3]

decimal_dust = 6

outputs = {( round(x, decimal_dust), round(y, decimal_dust), round(z, decimal_dust) )
    for (x, y, z) in inputs}

print(outputs)
```

Yields:

```
{(5.76, 9.842, 3.001), (1.123457, 2.0, 3.0)}
```